How to make the local service go through the proxy and return a response packet?
I can control A: 192.168.88.1 , B: 192.168.88.129
I want all traffic to B to go through a proxy of A:8888 and back to the requesting IP.
any Address when accessing B:  B -> A:8888 -> any
